# If a user logs on to a server side, how does a client side know this?

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the rules in firebase. If I let the user connect to my site, via firebase in Node.js, server side, how can I know on a client side that this user is currently online?

I only want a user logged in to access the site. How can I prevent access to requests, in client side, to everyone, and allow only someone connected?

I tried to use it:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
     }    
  }
}
```

But it does not work, and it also makes sense that it will not work, what can be done instead, that only those who are connected can use actions related to firebase on the site?

For long weeks I have been trying to fix this problem, it is a very simple problem in my opinion. My code is cumbersome and very long, I want to add it, but it will complicate my question.

My question is, if a user connects through a server side, and I do not have access to auth, how can I prevent access to requests, in client side, to everyone, and allow only someone connected?

**update: signing**

```js
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };

  const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user);

  if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors);

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((token) => {
      db.collection('users')
        .where("email", "==", user.email)
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          data.forEach((doc) => {

            let userHandle = doc.data().handle;
            db.collection("users")
              .doc(userHandle)
              .get()
              .then((doc) => {
                let user = doc.data();
                db.collection('users').doc(userHandle)
                  .set(user)
                  .then(() => {
                    return res.json({ token: token });
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
                  });

              }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });


          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        });



    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
    });
};
```

**update 2: Example of a client side function.**

```js
export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => {
    return async dispatch => {

        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('conversations')
            .where('user_uid_1', 'in', [user.uid_1, user.uid_2])
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

                const conversations = [];

                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_1 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_2)
                        ||
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_2 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_1)
                    ) {
                        conversations.push(doc.data())
                    }

                });

                dispatch({
                    type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                    payload: { conversations }
                })

                //console.log(conversations);
                //return res.json(conversations);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Firebase's server-side SDKs and APIs don't sign a user in in any way that would show up in `request.auth` in your rules. Can you show how you're signing the user in?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Of course, hope what I added can help you, please update me

Comment: This looks like code that runs client-side: `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. You may be using Node/NPM to build the app, but that call runs client-side. If I look at your opening sentence, it looks like you want https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence, but then the rest of your question and code doesn't map to that. Can you clarify, reduce the scope/code further?

Comment: I have a code I added on the client side, but is unaware of the current logged in user. That's why I'm unable to run the auth test in rules. I added an example of such a code.

Comment: The problem is still not clear to me. The `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)` API is only available in client-side SDKs, and clients that are signed in have a `request.auth` value in security rules. Code that connects from the server-side or doesn't sign in, doesn't have a `request.auth` value in the security rules.

Comment: I can connect through the `.signInWithEmailAndPassword (user.email, user.password)` when I use it in nodejs, could it be that nodejs is a client side and I only need to add the auth there?

Comment: As I've said from the start, the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is only available in client-side SDKs, so likely code that runs inside the user's browser.

Comment: Okay thanks! , from what I understand then, a simple check of auth in nodejs, will solve the problem?

Comment: If you are connecting with node.js (signInWithEmailAndPassword ) you're not logged into 'server side', you are still logged in on the client side. This results in an Auth variable for you to work with and Rules apply. The only 'server side' login in through the console and that's not what you appear to be doing.